# super in a metaclass

Tags: python, metaclass

Recently, I used a metaclass to implement a singleton. Then, I tried to understand how this `__metaclass__` stuff works. To do so, I wrote this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

class Meta(type):
    _instance = None
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('meta: init')
        #return super(Meta, cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('meta: new')
        return super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('meta: call')
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(cls._instance.__class__)
        return cls._instance



class ClassA():

    __metaclass__ = Meta
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.val = np.random.randint(1000)
        print('classA: init')


    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classA: new')
        return super(ClassA, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classA: call')
        return super(ClassA, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class ClassB():

    __metaclass__ = Meta
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classB: init')
        self.val = np.random.randint(1000)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classB: new')
        return super(ClassB, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classB: call')
        return super(ClassB, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class ClassC(ClassB):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classC: init')

        super(ClassC, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.test = 3

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classC: new')
        return super(ClassC, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classC: call')
        return super(ClassC, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)



if __name__ == '__main__':


    a1 = ClassA()
    b1 = ClassB()
    a2 = ClassA()
    b2 = ClassB()
    c1 = ClassC()

    print(a1.val)
    print(b1.val)
    print(a2.val)
    print(b2.val)
```

I have two questions about it:

- Why does `cls._instance` is `__main__.ClassA object` (or `__main__.ClassA object`)? Should it not be a parent instance as it is created with `super`?
- Why nothing (neither `__call__` nor `__init__`) inside `ClassC` is called when creating a `ClassC` instance but only the `ClassB.__call__` (as it inherits from it)?

Comment: What is `__super__`? There is no such special method or attribute in Python. Are you talking about the `super()` object?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's a stripped-down version of your code with some "noise" removed for readability.

```
import random

class Meta(type):
    _instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('meta: call: %s' % cls)
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("meta: call: returning %s@%s" % (cls._instance.__class__, id(cls._instance)))
        return cls._instance


class ClassA(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classA: new')
        return super(ClassA, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.val = random.randint(1, 1000)
        print('classA: init')


class ClassB(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classB: new')
        return super(ClassB, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classB: init')
        self.val = random.randint(1, 1000)

class ClassC(ClassB):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classC: new')
        return super(ClassC, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('classC: init')
        super(ClassC, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.test = 3


def main():
    a1 = ClassA()
    b1 = ClassB()
    a2 = ClassA()
    b2 = ClassB()
    c1 = ClassC()

    print(a1.val)
    print(b1.val)
    print(a2.val)
    print(b2.val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now your questions:

> Why does cls._instance is **main**.ClassA object (or **main**.ClassA object)? Should it not be a parent instance as it is created with super?

No, why ? In your case, when calling `ClassA()`, you actually invoke `Meta.__call__(ClassA)`. `super(Meta, cls)` will select the next class in `Meta.__mro__`, which is `type`, and so invoke `type.__call__(Meta, ClassA)`. `type.__call__(Meta, ClassA)` will in turn invoke `ClassA.__new__()` and `ClassA.__init__()`. So of course (hopefully, else you could hardly use inheritance at all), you do get a `ClassA` instance back.

As a general rule: `super(CurrentClass, obj_or_cls).something()` will select the `something` implementation in the "parent" class (actually in the next class in the `__mro__`) but the `self` (or `cls` or whatever) first argument will still point to `self` (or `cls` etc). IOW, you are selecting a parent implementation of a method, but this method will *still* get the current object/class as first argument.

> Why nothing (neither `__call__` nor `__init__`) inside ClassC is called when creating a ClassC instance but only the `ClassB.__call__` (as it inherits from it)

`ClassC.__call__()` is not called because nothing in your code calls it. It's `ClassC.__metaclass__.__call__()` which is responsible for `ClassC` instanciation. You'd need to call an *instance* of `ClassC` to have `ClassC.__call__()` invoked.

`ClassC.__init__()` is not invoked because actually no instance of `ClassC` is ever created. The reason here is that you first create an instance of `ClassB`. At this point (first instanciation of `ClassB`), `ClassB` has no attribute `_instance`, so the attribute is looked up on it's parent class `object`. Since `object` has no attribute `_instance` either, the lookup continues on `ClassB.__class__`, which is `Meta`. This one does have an `_instance` attribute, which is `None`, so you do create a `ClassB` instance and bind it to `ClassB._instance` (sus creating the attribute in `ClassB.__dict__`).

Then when you try to instanciate `ClassC`, the `if cls._instance is None` test will first lookup `_instance` on `ClassC`. At this point, `ClassC` does *not* have an `_instance` attribute, so it's looked up on `ClassC` first parent (next class in the mro), which is `ClassB`. Since you already instanciated `ClassB` once, the lookup ends here, resolving `ClassC._instance` to `ClassB.__dict__["_instance"]` , so what you get back *is* the already created `ClassB` instance.

If you want a working implementation, you have to get rid of `Meta._instance` and either set `_instance` to `None` on each class in `Meta.__init__()`:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kw):
        cls._instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('meta: call: %s' % cls)
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("meta: call: returning %s@%s" % (cls._instance.__class__, id(cls._instance)))
        return cls._instance
```

or replace the test in `Meta.__call__()` with a `getattr()`:

```
class Meta(type):

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('meta: call: %s' % cls)
        if not getattr(cls, "_instance", None):
            cls._instance = super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("meta: call: returning %s@%s" % (cls._instance.__class__, id(cls._instance)))
        return cls._instance
```